# AWS auto-scaling websocket cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-route53

So I am changing lots of my sites' "live" updates (currently working over AJAX) to use Websockets. Tried Pusher.com, pricing ridiculously high for my amount of traffic, so I got slanger (cheers Steve!) up on a big fat EC2 instance, redis EC instance, all good. Now for about 100M frames/day it seems to work fine, but I'd like to think ahead and consider what happens when I'll have even more traffic.

AWS ELBs do not support WS communication as I have read around here and on the AWS forums so far (quite lame considering people are asking for this since WS first popped up, thanks AWS!). So I am thinking to:

0) start with one instance, ws.mydomain.com

1) set up an auto-scaling group

2) cloudwatch alert on average CPU/memory usage

3) when it goes above 75% fire a SQS message saying something like "scale up now"

4) when message at #3 is received by some other random server polling the queue then fire up a new instance, add it to the group (ohnoes, that AWS API again!) and add the public IP to the Route53 DNS for ws.mydomain.com, so there will be 2 of them

5) when load drops fire another message, basically doing everything the other way around

So the question is: Could this work or should it be easier to go with an ELB in front of the slanger nodes?

TIA

Later edit:

1) don't care if we don't get the client IP

2) the slanger docs advertise that connection states are stored into redis so it does not matter to which node the clients connect to, so we don't need any session stickiness

Comment: ELB, of course, *does* work with websockets, just not in HTTP mode.  The ELB needs to be in TCP mode, and your websocket server implementation needs to support the `PROXY` protocol, if you want to know the IP address of your websocket clients.

Comment: hmmm so if I drop an ELB in TCP mode in front of them instances running the slanger service it will just work?

Comment: Well, as they say, "yes, almost, sort of."  With just one instance behind it, yes, though you lose the source IP info unless slanger supports the [proxy protocol V1](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/07/30/elastic-load-balancing-now-supports-proxy-protocol/).  With multiple instances, you have a new issue, which is that you may not have a mechanism to enable you to send messages to the correct node.  Try it, though, and you then may have a different question to ask, here.

Comment: Michael, slanger seems to use redis to keep track of connection states so a client can connect to any node in the cluster (as they say). the source IP does not matter, we use channels with specific names based on the HTTP sessions users start on the web application, pretty hard to guess and even if someone does manage somehow to find an existing channel, the data is public anyway.